# opengl es 1.1 perform greater than or less than operations

Tags: image-processing, opengl-es-1.1

I am working on an image processing application on In OpenGL ES 1.1 I need to find number of pixels less than some value (lets say < 0.4 ) and find the mean.

The method I thought of is,
Load the texture to GPU, create a FBO of the same size
if pixel value is > 0.4 draw 1 at the FBO
set the Viewport to 1 pixel and render and the value is the mean.

I couldn’t find a way to do greater than or less than operation. Can someone please let me know whether this approach is OK and a way to do less than operation in OpenGL ES 1.1.

Thank you